# How to speed my too-slow ssh login?

Tags: ssh

Running `ssh user@hostname` takes ~30s. Here's the scenario:

- this is a VM on the local LAN
- Windows and Mac machines get instant login
- am using Debian and I could reproduce with an Ubuntu machine
- someone using Ubuntu says that logging into my machine (local LAN) is also instant
- using hostname IP address takes about half as much time (~15s)

[**update**]

Using `ssh -vvv user@hostname`, here's where it waits the most:

```
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
```

And then it waits a bit here:

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found
```

Comment: do you use password or pubkey authentication? and if password, is the a `id_dsa` or `id_rsa` file in your `~/.ssh`? maybe your ssh installation tries the wrong authentication first and your server doesn't deny but simply ignore that request resulting in that 30s timeout

Comment: @tobias I use password and I don't have `"~/.ssh"` file. That's a directory, and it only has `"known_hosts"` file in it.

Comment: It looks like you have a 15s DNS timeout. Maybe the server is doing a DNS lookup; if you can, make sure you have `UseDNS no` in `sshd_config` on the server. In any case, run `ssh -vvv user@hostname` to see where the login is hanging.

Comment: @gil Thanks. I updated the question. I'll ask the admin to check for that __UseDNS__ setting.

Comment: @Tshepang: Oh, you're using Kerberos (GSSAPI) authentication. I'm not familiar with it. If it's misconfigured, maybe it's causing the delay. This is something you can ask your admin. DNS might be a red herring; it's the most common cause in the wild, but perhaps your problem is different.

Comment: @gil Does that mean that __UseDNS__ is no longer valid option?

Comment: @Tshepang: `UseDNS no` is a good idea *most* of the time (but in a managed network where the admin can trust the DNS `UseDNS yes` can be useful). I'd wait and see what the admin says.

Comment: @gilles What ssh client are you using? I use OpenSSH.

Comment: Remember to restart the ssh server, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/103889/how-do-you-stop-restart-ssh and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-start-stop-ssh-server/

Answer (score 35):

Edit your "**/etc/ssh/ssh_config**" and comment out these lines:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Alternatively, having the following in SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`) also works:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer! (1) Is it a normal speed for ssh login connection to take the time of the cursor flashing 7 times? (2) Why does it work by commenting out     `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no`? @Tshepang

Comment: @Tim (1) that's way too long... depending on the connection, I don't expect it to take over 2 seconds; (2) I have no idea, just that it works

Comment: The default for GSSAPIAuthentication in most versions of OpenSSH is "no", but some distros set it to "yes" in the sshd_config and ssh_config files.  If you don't need/use it, it slows down the connection / authentication handshake.

Comment: If LDAP/AD authentication is in use, won't disabling GSSAPI cause a simple bind to be used, potentially sending passwords over the network in plaintext?

Comment: Verify all the nameservers still exist in /etc/resolv.conf.  If they don't, take them out.  This resolved my issue.

Comment: The GSSAPI authentication attempt requires some extra DNS lookups. The root cause for significant wait time at SSH authentication is often a DNS lookup that is timing out.

Answer (score 33):

I had this problem and resolved it by turning off Reverse DNS resolution in SSH.

So in `sshd_config` on the *server* change this:

```
 #UseDNS yes
```

to this:

```
UseDNS no
```

Comment: I did the change (though I had no commented-out __UseDNS__ option), reset my ssh server, and still the same problem.

Comment: @Tshe hmm, odd. The only speed problems I've ever had with SSH was due to this.

Comment: I was skeptical as I use to login using the IP address (home LAN), but this solution fixed my issue.  For Google's sake, though it was occurring just after, the delay had nothing to do with the "key: /home/mylogin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))" message (when running `ssh -vvv`).

Comment: 2020 and we still had that problem :) for Googlers' sake: restart the sshd service afterwards before testing..

Comment: If you proxy-jump through another host on the same local network as the target, this can occur because the target tries to reverse lookup the jump hosts local IP.

Answer (score 7):

Have you verified your DNS setup?

Try the setting `mdns off` in `/etc/host.conf`.

This disables the mdns resolution and helped me a lot.

EDIT:

It seems gentoo is handling this a bit different. To disable multicast DNS lookups, you have to change the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.
There should be something like:

```
hosts:          files mdns
```

Change it to:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: +1 good idea. @Tshepang does ssh connect faster when you use hostname's IP directly?

Comment: @tobias takes half as much time

Comment: I'm getting `/etc/host.conf: line 2: bad command `mdns off'` when I run `ssh user@hostname`.

Comment: Seems this is an outdated setting, since glibc 2.3.x (2006): https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-476558-highlight-mdns.html. What are you using (OS, glic version)?

Comment: What do you mean by *Have you verified your DNS setup?*

Comment: You are telling it takes only half the time when you use the IP address. This means you have a problem with your name resolution (IP=>FQDN or FQDN=>IP). So first take a look at your DNS config and then try to find out whether you have a problem with ssh or not.

Comment: Added an example for gentoo. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I had `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` and changed it to `hosts: files dns`. It's now instant. Is that kool?

Comment: Also, can you comment on my glibc note.

Comment: OS is: SLES 11 SP1, glibc version 2.11.1

Answer (score 2):

Adding the host name to `/etc/hosts` can sometimes resolve this issue.

Comment: Works for a single hostname, but Earlz's solution is more generic (and fixes the same issue).

Answer (score 1):

Also check if `nscd` is installed and running.

Not having a dns cache can increase the time it takes to resolve the PTR record (assuming that the ssh client is performing a dns reverse lookup for the server's IP address)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in the Windows 2008 R2 environment but "useDNS no" does not work.

I try adding to hosts file the IP and host of the connecting server and its faster by 30secs. Which makes me think that the resolution might be in DNS.

I try adding DNS servers but this doesnt resolve it.

My server have two DNS suffix. 1 for the corporate domain where the server belong (domain.com) and the other for its external interface connecting to a private network (domain.net).

DNS suffix order is domain.net first then domain.com next

My SFTP/SSH clients are in the the corporate domain. By the way problematic clients are from corporate domain.

What works for me is that I make domain.com first then domain.net second

The 2m30s connection delay before became 3-4s only .

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `/etc/hosts`.

I have changed my hostname using `hostnamectl set-hostname` and updated IPv4 address in `/etc/hosts`, but forgot to update IPv6 address:

```
127.0.0.1              localhost
45.12.34.56            srv1.foobar.com
2a00:abc:123:6432::1   srv1.foobar.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, but they seemed to be client related.
In my case, using Putty as an SSH2 client I had to switch the 'Internet protocol version' under the connection menu from Auto to IPv4. I didn't investigate why Auto doesn't work faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`gpg-agent` to cache `ssh` keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#SSH_agent) & you also run `gnome-keyring` you need to:

- [deactivate the `ssh` component in `gnome-keyring`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Disable_keyring_daemon_components).

In a secure desktop environment ([with `hidepid`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Security#hidepid)) it is less problematic to just run `ssh-agent` as a [systemd --user service.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Start_ssh-agent_with_systemd_user) & enable `ssh` key caching in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

I use secure `Ciphers` / `MACs` / `KexAlgorithms` (256 / 512 bit only) in my remote `sshd_config` & also in my local `~/.ssh/config`:

- https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html
- https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh

Debugging the slow connection with `ssh -vvv user@host` showed the `ssh` client trying lots of different combinations of keys & options.

To speed up the key exchange it helped to:

- **remove weak keys** from the remote server (`DSA` / `ECDSA`)
- set a **default** `ssh` key in my local `~/.ssh/config` that matched my strict configuration:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

With these changes the `publickey` became accepted within the same second.