# SSH on my local network - problem with login

Tags: debian, ssh, authentication

I'm having problem with logging into my local-network-linux (server) ssh with Putty (and with Linux terminal, too)

When my server shows me request to insert username, I insert "root" and I do press enter.

I am waiting about seven seconds before it requests my password!

[I also looked at this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/how-to-speed-my-too-slow-ssh-login)

and tried accepted answer, also with command

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

It didn't work. My friend told me that I should have to use another SSH deamon, but I don't know which. What could I do now?

my current /etc/ssh/ssh_config config:

```
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another SSH daemon.  You may need to *explicitly* disable (as opposed to simply commenting out) `GSSAPIAuthentication` and `GSSAPIKeyExchange` in the client; the other question didn't mention the latter, probably because it's a recent addition and I think it's still vendor-applied third party patches.  (Debian Squeeze, at least, definitely has it.)  `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials` doesn't need to be touched, as it is only looked at when `GSSAPIAuthentication` is enabled.

If the above doesn't do it, your nest step is to use `strace` to see what it's doing during the pause.

```
strace /usr/bin/ssh -vvv host
```

This assumes it's the client end; the server is a bit harder to debug.  If it comes to that, you will need to disable the normal server (in the modern world this is `service ssh stop`) and then do something like

```
sudo strace -f /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

Don't forget to reactivate the normal server with `service ssh start` afterward!

Comment: It still takes a long of time to show it, maybe the same

Comment: @genesis: was editing when you commented; see revision.

Comment: I'll have to try it on linux (PC) right?

Comment: when I tried "root@kufr:/etc/ssh# ssh localhost
root@localhost's password:
" it was imediatelly :/

Comment: your last edit: "root@kufr:~# service sshd stop
sshd: unrecognized service
"

Comment: `localhost` avoids a number of checks, I believe. And yes, this is all assuming OpenSSH on Linux; I can't help with debugging via PuTTY or Cygwin's OpenSSH, beyond possibly the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: *sigh* serves me right for not checking; it seems to vary on every distribution. `ssh`, not `sshd`. Editing.

Comment: @genesis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/785/discussion-between-geekosaur-and-genesis)

Comment: I'm ready there ...

Comment: @genesis If you need to debug the server, keep the normal `sshd` running and start another one on a different port: `sshd -ddd -p 2222`

Answer (score 0):

Could be a DNS issue, if so try uncommenting:

```
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
```

so that it becomes

```
   GSSAPITrustDNS no
```

It will work around the issues for now, however the real fix is to fix the DNS problem.
As a side note adding -vvv to your SSH command will print out a lot more information and give you a better idea of where to look e.g.:

```
ssh -vvv <user>@<server>
```