# Is cp faster than rsync during the first run?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, cp, ssd, large-files

I am currently using `rsync` to copy a 73GB file from a Samsung portable SSD T7 to an HPC cluster.

```
rsync -avh path/to/dataset me@server.somewhere:/path/to/dest
```

The following applies:

1. My local machine (where my T7 is connected) is a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 20.
2. The T7 transfer speeds should be up to approx. 1000MB/s.
3. Network gives me an approximate upload speed of 7.9Mbps.
4. Rsync transfer speed is probably bottlenecking this to 1-5MB/s according to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/109780/how-to-speed-up-rsync).

The problem is that the move is still not done after 9 hours. According to [1](https://superuser.com/questions/109780/how-to-speed-up-rsync), using `cp` instead is better with an empty directory (for the first time). I do not understand this or whether it is actually true. Can someone explain this?

Comment: It's going over a network? You need to look at the path and find which link has the minimum speed. That 1000MB/s also represents 8Gbps.

Comment: @Bib, sorry I've only just begun using Linux heavily recently. What do you mean by finding which link please?

Comment: I reach the HPC cluster via password-protected ssh, if that is what you asked for. With regards to what the network is, sorry I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I mean what's the physical network you use to connect from local box to remote one. Over the internet (if yes what is roughly your connection bandwidth), over local wired network (ethernet on the same building), something else?

Comment: Ah yes. So if I'm understanding correctly, I'm connected over the internet (Ziggo). Current speed tests point to an approximate upload speed of 7.9Mbps.

Comment: 8Mbps is around 1 MB per second. Whatever tool you use to copy 73GB (uncompressed) over this network (upload from your local box), time will be more than 73000/60/60 ~ 20 hours, It would be 1 day. Seems better `rsync` with `-P` and probably `-z`.

Comment: The post you linked refers a case with many files, between a hard disk and a usb device, locally. Your case is different.

Comment: Yes, I figured it should take a day because of the network bottleneck. It's still going, and now I guess I'm too far in to consider other options. I'll wait and hopefully by the end of today it will be done! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that,

1. Your network speed is approximately 8 Mb/s.
2. Your `rsync` runs at about 1-5 MB/s.

Given that 1 MB/s is approximately 10 Mb/s I'd say that `rsync` is doing you a big favour.

Me, I'd probably have added compression with `-z`, and since you're using `rsync` with sensible flags over a network connection it's probably with interrupting it and restarting with compression. It'll just pick up where it left off.

Quick calculation: 73 GB is 73,000 MB<sup>*</sup>, which is 730,000 Mb<sup>‡</sup>. Approximately. You've got a network speed of 8 Mb/s, so that means the copy should take around 730,000/8 = 91,250 seconds. 25 hours, assuming theoretical maximum use of network bandwidth.

<sup>* Why 1000:1 instead of 1024:1? Partly because GB:MB strictly is 1000:1, but largely because this is an approximation calculation</sup>
<sup>‡ Why 10:1 instead of 8:1 as suggested by 8 bits to 1 byte? Two reasons: (a) it's an O(n) approximation, and (b) there's packet/protocol overhead to consider.</sup>

---

Now to try and answer the question strictly as asked, which is, "*Is cp faster than rsync during the first run?*". If you're using `cp` you need to have something managing the transport between the local and remote servers; that could be something like `sshfs` or NFS, or alternatively you might mean `scp`.

1. `cp` over an NFS mounted filesystem. With a well-tuned network this is probably fairly efficient.
2. `cp` over `sshfs`. This will include not only encryption overheads of `ssh` but also the translation between kernel and userspace for the FUSE implementation of the filesystem. Inefficient.
3. `scp` (implicitly over `ssh`). This will include encryption overhead from `ssh`. Acceptable, and might futher benefit from link compression (`-C`).
4. `rsync` (implicitly over `ssh` since we've not mentioned `rsyncd`).  This will include encryption overhead from `ssh`. Acceptable, and might futher benefit from protocol compression (`-z`).

I've not taken quantitative performance metrics; these are qualitative assessments. However, note the comments on a similar answer [Why is scp so slow and how to make it faster?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238207/100397), although to be fair that's discussing comparative transfer rates of multiple files rather than one large one.

However, where `rsync` wins across a network connection is that it's restartable. With the right flags (i.e. `--partial`) even mid-way through a transfer. For a single 73GB file taking around 25 hours to transfer that's a massive potential advantage.

Comment: 73 GB = 584000 Mbit --> 20h 17m at 8 Mbit/s (21h 46m if it's 73 GiB).

Comment: @Kusalananda approximation of 1000s for G / M and 10:1 for M to m. It's an O(n) calc not a perfect one

Comment: Just so you know, the rsync took a little just under 25 hours :)

Comment: While this answer does not answer the original question as to whether cp would be faster, I'm going to accept it anyway since it was still very helpful, and the time estimation was very accurately stated. Please suggest if I should re-edit my question title so that it is more aligned with this answer since it's still useful.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @mesllo I've attempted to answer the question for you strictly as asked

Comment: Super informative, thanks. With regards to the `--partial` flag, I did not specify it in my `rsync`. I understand that this would keep partially transferred files in the destination, but I also read that this may cause some corruption if you stop and restart the `rsync` later. Is this correct? Also, given that I stopped and restarted `rsync` a few times without this `--partial` flag, if there is a partially transferred file that is suddenly halted, what happens upon restarting? Will the `rsync` start from that file again, or skip it?

Comment: @mesilo for future reference, you will have to use `--append` to resume, see [rsync resume after interrupted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted). Test it locally with smaller files to see behaviour.

Comment: @roaima I think it was ~ 20h for the data, and the rest was the encryption overhead you mention, and I guess some user's upload for other purposes.

Comment: @mesllo "_this [the `--partial` flag] may cause some corruption if you stop and restart the rsync later. Is this correct?_". No. You'll not get corruption. Just make sure you **do not** use `--append` unless you can absolutely guarantee 100% that the source file didn't change. Safer not to use it and let `rsync` figure it out

Comment: @roaima After an interrupted transfer with `rsync -P`, a second `rsync` without `--append` or `--append-verify` doesn't seem to append to the partial file (for what I tested). (And of course talking about a stable source file, one-off big file transfer)

Comment: @thanasisp it does, but not in-place. First it checksums the existing blocks using its usual algorithm to ensure that what it's got matches on both sides. As it does this it starts to build a fresh copy, which it then continues to extend by copying across the network. You can force an in-place copy with the `--in-place` flag. You can cut out the sanity check for the already-copied file with `--append`, but personally I don't usually recommend this as it removes one of the safety checks that the file has copied correctly.

Comment: Okay, so just to recap. The `rsync` command I ran neither did it use `--append` nor `--partial`. I interrupted this `rsync` process a few times. Since I didn't use `--append`, does it mean that my transfer didn't happen correctly? How can I verify this? At a glance, it seems that it happened just fine, but a sanity check would be nice :)

Comment: Don't use `--append` unless you really understand exactly under what circumstances it's safe to do so. It is always safe _not_ to use `--append`.

Comment: If you want a sanity check on the file contents, `md5sum` will provide it